# Using single NSTextField in multiple NSViews

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa-touch, nsview

I've got three NSViews (we'll call them "main", "one" and "two"). The "main" view acts as a container for "one" and "two" which are subviews:

```
[main addSubview:one];
... 
// "one" gets replaced by "two" at a later point
...
[main replaceSubview:one with:two];
```

The issue I have is that an `NSTextField` resides on "one" which I would also like to show up on "two", so it's there when "one" is replaced. The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to reference or duplicate the `NSTextField` so that it can appear on both views and be used by both.

[image]

Is it possible to use the same `NSTextField` in multiple `NSViews`?

Comment: Are `main`, `one`, and `two` all of the same class? Each view can only see referencing outlets that are in the same class as it.

Comment: `main` has it's own `NSView` subclass, `one` and `two` are together in `AppDelegate` as `NSViews`, which gets the `main` view subclass included.

Comment: So `main` is a subclass of `NSView`, and `one` and `two` are regular `NSView`s?

Comment: One and the same _instance_ cannot be in two places. Two _different_ instances of the same class can be in two places, but not one and the same _instance_. Why do you even think you need this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Duh***, the answer was right in front of my face...

```
NSRect textRect = NSMakeRect(0,0,200,22); // X, Y, W, H
NSTextField *text = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:textRect];

[text setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"foobar"]];

[main addSubview:one];
[one addSubview:text];
... 
// "one" gets replaced by "two" at a later point
...
[main replaceSubview:one with:two];
[two addSubview:text]
```

I just used an `NSMakeRect` and initialized it with the `NSTextField` and all is good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to achieve, but: no, it's not possible for a view to be in two different superviews. A view has only a single superview. A view hierarchy is strictly a tree structure.

You can, of course, create two identical text fields to appear in two places in the view hierarchy. However, if you later make changes to one of them and want them to remain identical, you have to make the same changes to the other.

You can also remove the text field from one superview and add it to another at run time, for example when you switch from one view being visible to the other. If you're using auto layout, that can be annoying, since removing the view from the view hierarchy will also remove any constraints between it and its superview and siblings. And you'll have to recreate appropriate constraints when you put the text field into its new superview.

Finally, an outlet can only refer to single view. That is, an outlet is an object pointer and, as such, can only refer to a single object at a time. If you have two separate text fields (even if configured identically) and you want to refer to them from code, you'll need two separate outlets.

Comment: I think what he wants is some kind of binding that would give them the same content at all times. But it's been so long since I've programmed for Mac OS X that I can't remember how to do that...

Comment: Actually, it's "she" :), but yes I want the subviews of the main view to include an nstextfield that is the same content as matt mentioned. Currently I'm doing it the hard way, but created completely different nstextfields for each subview and it's a huge pain.

Comment: `mainview` (nsview subclass)-> nstextfield (on subview one) -> (would like the same nstextfield on subview two).

Comment: If you just want text fields which have the same content, you can do that multiple ways. One way would be to have two outlets to the two separate text fields and, whenever you set the content (e.g. `stringValue`) of one, set the same content on the other. Another way would be to use bindings, and bind the Value binding of both text fields to the same controller and key path.